# Invoking functions multiple times, but the first time it would print something weird

Tags: javascript

```
function counter() {
    var n = 0;

    return function counter() {
        n += 1;

        return n;
    }
}



var count = counter();

console.log('counter() returns: ' + count);
console.log('invoking the function returns: ' + count());
console.log('invoking the function returns: ' + count());
console.log('invoking the function returns: ' + count());
```

This function returns a single number and every time it is invoked, the function returns a number that is "one" number higher than the one before.

The problem with this code is this:

```
console.log('counter() returns: + count);
```

This would print the actual code of inner function of a counter which is printed 
`function counter(){ n+= 1; return n; }`
instead of 0. Is there anyway to fix it? The other console statements print correctly, which prints out 1 2 3

Comment: The code is printed because, the inner function is returned when outer function is called. To fix it, just call the `count()` function.

Comment: In that place you print `count`, in other places you print `count()`. The two are not the same. You do not have the code there that would allow you to print `0`.

Comment: It's not something weird, but the string representation of the *function* `count`. What else did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case the output you get is the function definition ,since you are returning the function to a varibale by assigning `var count = counter()`. You need to call count like `count()` so that it executes the function definition

```
console.log('counter() returns: ' + count());
```

If you want to print `0` you need to initialize `var n = -1` because otherwise your result is will start from `1` as it value is incremented and then returned

```js
function counter() {
    var n = -1;

    return function counter() {
        n += 1;

        return n;
    }
}



var count = counter();

console.log('counter() returns: ' + count());
console.log('invoking the function returns: ' + count());
console.log('invoking the function returns: ' + count());
console.log('invoking the function returns: ' + count());
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way your code can print `0`, because the value is incremented before it is returned. If you want the first number returned to be `0`, start at `-1`.

```js
function counter() {
    var n = -1;
    return function () {
        n += 1;
        return n;
    };
}

var count = counter();

console.log('counter() returns: ' + count);
console.log('invoking the function returns: ' + count());
console.log('invoking the function returns: ' + count());
console.log('invoking the function returns: ' + count());
```

`console.log(count)` prints the function itself to the console. That's expected.